# Convert bat command in vbs

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

i need convert 1 command in bat, to vbs. Can anybody help me?

```
del /f /q /s "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.Outlook\*.*"
```

I tried to copy some commands like from others but I did did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "pure" vbscript without calling the cmd:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

homedrive=wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%HOMEDRIVE%" )
homepath=wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%HOMEPATH%" )
objFSO.DeleteFile(homedrive & homepath & "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.Outlook*.*"),true
```

Comment: +1, although I'd recommend using `BuildPath` for constructing the paths.

Answer (score 0):

```
Shell("cmd.exe /c del /f /q /s ""%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.Outlook*.*""")
```